# Filter pandas column based on frequency of occurrence

Tags: pandas

My df:

```
data = [
    {'Part': 'A', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10},
    {'Part': 'B', 'Value': 12, 'Delivery': 8.5},
    {'Part': 'C', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.1},
    {'Part': 'D', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.3},
    {'Part': 'E', 'Value': 11, 'Delivery': 9.2},
    {'Part': 'F', 'Value': 15, 'Delivery': 7.3},
    {'Part': 'G', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.1},
    {'Part': 'H', 'Value': 12, 'Delivery': 8.1},
    {'Part': 'I', 'Value': 12, 'Delivery': 8.0},
    {'Part': 'J', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.2},
    {'Part': 'K', 'Value': 8,  'Delivery': 12.5}    
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I wish to filter a dataframe out of given dataframe so that it contain only the most frequent occurring "value".

Expected output:

```
data = [
    {'Part': 'A', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10},
    {'Part': 'C', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.1},
    {'Part': 'D', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.3},
    {'Part': 'G', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.1},
    {'Part': 'J', 'Value': 10, 'Delivery': 10.2}
]

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use ``mode`` : ``df.loc[df.Value.eq(df.Value.mode().item())]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and seelct first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].mode().iat[0])]
```

Or compare by first index value in Series created by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), because by default values are sorted by counts:

```
df1 = df[df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].value_counts().index[0])]
print (df1)
  Part  Value  Delivery
0    A     10      10.0
2    C     10      10.1
3    D     10      10.3
6    G     10      10.1
9    J     10      10.2
```